# React: How to return useRef.current.value from inside useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window, use-effect, use-ref

I was planning to use useRef.current.values in a project, and a guide I was reading recommended returning values from inside useEffect.  The guide showed the setup, but no example for using values.

I'm stumped on how to get useRef values out of useEffect.  I see values inside the pageRef.current object via console.log that get populated after page render.  useEffect complained when I tried to return the values - the error message says you can only return a function.

Here's the Nav component I am using (`Nav` is the App entry point and the pages are rendered in `PageContainer` at the bottom, hookrouter-style):

```
const Nav = () => {
    const pageRef = useRef({});
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);
    const routeResult = useRoutes(directions);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (pageRef.current) {
            let pageHeight = pageRef.current.currentHeight;
            let pageWidth = pageRef.current.currentWidth; // etc.
            console.log(pageRef.current.currentWidth); // example
            return pageWidth; // error, can only return a function
        }
    }, [pageRef]);

    console.log(pageRef.current.clientWidth);

    const backgroundClickHandler = () => {
        if (isOpen) {
            setIsOpen(!isOpen);
        }
  };
  
  const toggleClickHandler = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  
    return (
        <div>
            <ToggleContainer>
                <button
                    className='fas fa-bars fa-2x'
                    onClick={toggleClickHandler}
                ></button>
            </ToggleContainer>
            {isOpen && <NavWrapper>{NavList()}</NavWrapper>}
            <ClickContainer onClick={backgroundClickHandler} isOpen={isOpen}>
                <PageContainer ref={pageRef}>
                    {routeResult || <NotFoundPage />}
                </PageContainer>
            </ClickContainer>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Nav;
```

So my questions are:

1. Why retrieve useRef values from inside useEffect, instead of
   directly accessing `pageRef.current.value`? Isn't it returning info from
   the DOM, not updating the DOM directly?  Returning a `current.value`
   a side-effect?
2. Values inside useEffect for pageRef aren't being updated when
   resizing the window, even though pageRef is inside the array which
   useEffect is supposed to watch (?).
3. What's an example of a function to return a `pageRef.current.value`
   in this context?
4. Is there a better way to go about what I'm trying to accomplish
   here?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I am trying to get the rendered page height from the PageContainer, and also the viewport width.  I went with a different solution for the width, but I'm still curious how to get values out of this scenario.  Should I use createRef instead of useRef?

Comment: `useRef` is same as `createRef`, its just that `useRef` is a react hook and can be used inside functional component and `createRef` in class based components.

Answer (score 1):

Answers to your questions:

1. Your `useEffect` basically says that whenever `pageRef` changes, call this function. If done outside, it will call do your tasks on every render instead of doing the whenever `pageRef` values is changed. Also, in initial renders, it may give `undefined` values.

```
 useEffect(() => { // called whenever pageRef is changed
        if (pageRef.current) {
            let pageHeight = pageRef.current.currentHeight;
            let pageWidth = pageRef.current.currentWidth; // etc.
            console.log(pageRef.current.currentWidth); // example
        }
    }, [pageRef]);

    console.log(pageRef.current.clientWidth); // called on every render, be it because of pageRef change or not
```

2. Values inside pageRef will not change on resizing windows as you have not attached any `resize` event listeners to the DOM element
3. you can only return a function in `useEffect` which basically says that before running the same next time, run this function before. So it perfectly helps in cleanups or unsubscribing from events.
4. You can achieve what you are trying to accomplish with your way, you only need to attach `resize` event listener to the requrired DOM element and handle the same.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the succinct and helpful explanation.  The only thing that's confusing is the pageRef object gets updated without an event listener as long as it's outside useEffect... also an example of function inside useEffect would be super helpful

Comment: `pageRef` must be changing in your `PageContainier` which will trigger `useEffect`